# Opacity transition not working with two fixed position elements

Tags: css, css-position, z-index, transition, opacity

In my website, I have a YouTube-style progress bar (a thin line that is fixed to the top of the screen, loading from left to right) and a header over all of the content. Both of these elements have `position: fixed`.

When the page is finished loading, the progress bar gets `opacity: 0`. The progress bar has `transition: opacity 0.4s`, but **it's not transitioning, just appearing and disappearing**. This is my issue.

Here is an example of the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZJNaqJ

Ideally, any solution would involve changing CSS within either `.loader-outer` or `.loader`... not `#loader-wrapper`. This is because I'm pulling in an external progress bar component (I'm using React) and I'd rather not re-implement it if I don't have to.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 animation instead. If you want to trigger the animation at a specific event, add a style class name and set the animation attributes there. Then remove the style class name to stop the animation.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: palevioletred;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
}

.loader-outer {
}

.loader-wrapper {
}

.loader {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  animation-name:opacityAnimation;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration:2s;
}

@keyframes opacityAnimation {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  50% {opacity:1;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}

.content {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="header">
      header stuff here
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      body!
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="loader-outer">
    <div id="loader-wrapper">
      <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```